# Access key attribute is not working in the Firefox and Internet Explorer browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I created a button using the `accesskey` attribute:

```
<button title="Confort+" id="confort+" accesskey="X">Confort<span>+</span</button>
```

But I'm facing an issue with that code when I am on Firefox or Internet Explorer. The `accesskey` works only once in those two browser whereas in Chrome everything is working fine.
How can I fix this?

Firefox 52.9.0 and Internet Explorer 11.0.70.

Comment: Which key you are using for Mozilla

Comment: for mozilla is X. `Shift + Alt+ X ` @brk

Comment: I think it is `Alt+ Shift + X` the order matters

Comment: yeah !
sorry but it changes nothing all.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_test
i added this `accesskey="W"`
and sometime it's working and some not. i don't know why ?

Comment: it is working in mozilla

Comment: uh !
weird that it is not working consistenly in my mozilla and IE. The issue must come from my configuration or something like that.

Comment: No, the order of the keys `Alt` and `Shift` does not matter; `Alt + Shift + X` and `Shift + Alt + X` works exactly the same. This was tested on Firefox 67.0.4.